# How to convert image to postscript shape

Tags: java, svg, image-processing, jpeg, postscript

I have a java program that reads partial postscript files to produce postscript and PDF reports.

How can I create colour image (such as a logo or banner) resource to be included in the report?

There is already an existing colour logo as a postscript file.
Need to figure out how to create such files for new images.
Image can be any of the following formats: JPG, SVG or PNG.

As a workaround, I have already tried to improve a java application that converts JPG to postscript resource with 8bits resolution. 
However unable to figure out how to convert it to colour postscript resource with 24bits resolution.

I have tried many converters that converts image to ".PS" or ".EPS" files but none of them have similar code so can not be successfully integrated to the java application (please see the provided postscript code).

Following postscript code for colour logo that is already displayed in one of the reports. Is there any way that java program can read an image (JPG or SVG) and convert that to similar code:

```
/UniversityLogoResource {
newpath
0 84.2 moveto
474.8 84.2 lineto
474.8 0 lineto
0 0 lineto
0 84.2 lineto
closepath
1 1 1 setrgbcolor 
fill
newpath
8.688 74.76 moveto
18.592 74.69 28.498 74.75 38.402 74.73 curveto
52.57 74.726 66.738 74.738 80.906 74.724 curveto
80.902 53.286 80.904 31.848 80.906 10.408 curveto
80.89 9.728 80.964 9.04 80.852 8.362 curveto
59.504 8.326 38.156 8.358 16.806 8.348 curveto
14.144 8.324 11.48 8.394 8.818 8.31 curveto
8.846 29.606 8.82 50.902 8.836 72.198 curveto
8.858 73.044 8.872 73.898 8.694 74.73 curveto
8.688 74.76 lineto
closepath
0 0.565 0.749 setrgbcolor 
fill
newpath
8.694 74.73 moveto
8.872 73.898 8.858 73.044 8.836 72.198 curveto
8.82 50.902 8.846 29.606 8.818 8.31 curveto
8.636 8.506 8.55 8.736 8.564 9 curveto
8.568 30.598 8.566 52.196 8.564 73.794 curveto
8.584 74.11 8.626 74.422 8.694 74.73 curveto
closepath
0.275 0.608 0.69 setrgbcolor 
fill
}
```

Following code (alternative solution) trying to convert image to byte array with 24bits resolution. Is it possible to convert a colour image to array of bytes?:

```
private byte[] getImageBytesAt24BitsResolution() {
        int[] pixels = new int[realWidth * realHeight];
        PixelGrabber pixGrab = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0,  realWidth, realHeight, pixels, 0, realWidth);
        try {
            pixGrab.grabPixels();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        int size = realWidth * realHeight; 
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        int datumPos = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < realHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < realWidth; x++) {
                Color color = new Color(pixels[x + realWidth * y]);

                int rgb = color.getRGB();
                ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();

                Object pixel = cm.getDataElements(rgb, null);
                data[datumPos] = ((byte[]) pixel)[0];

                datumPos++;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Following java code creates the postscript resource file with the byte array `imageBytes` created in the above method `getImageBytesAt24BitsResolution()`:

```
        byte[] rleBytes = PSDecoders.rleEncode(imageBytes);
        // String[] asciiBytes = PSDecoders.ascii85Encode(rleBytes);
        String[] asciiBytes = PSDecoders.hexEncode(rleBytes);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("%===============================================================\n");
        sb.append("%%BeginResource: file " + (new File(mFileName).getName()) + " 1 0\n");
        sb.append("/" + postscriptID +".form\n");
        sb.append("<<\n");
        sb.append("/FormType 1\n");
        sb.append("/BBox[0 0 "+((int)Math.ceil(endWidth))+" "+((int)Math.ceil(endHeight))+"]\n");
        sb.append("/Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]\n");
        sb.append("/PaintProc{pop\n");
        sb.append("/DeviceGray setcolorspace gsave\n");
        sb.append(doubleFormat(endWidth)+" "+doubleFormat(endHeight)+" scale\n");
        sb.append("<<\n");
        sb.append("/Interpolate true\n");
        sb.append("/ImageType 1\n");
        sb.append("/Width "+realWidth+"\n");
        sb.append("/Height "+realHeight+"\n");
        sb.append("/ImageMatrix["+realWidth+" 0 0 -"+realHeight+" 0 "+realHeight+"]\n");
        sb.append("/BitsPerComponent "+resolution.getBits()+"\n");
        sb.append("/Decode[0 1]");
        sb.append("/DataSource\n<");
        for(String line : asciiBytes) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append(">\n/RunLengthDecode filter\n>>\n");
        sb.append("image grestore}\n>> def\n");
        sb.append("% -- proc call\n");
        sb.append("/" + postscriptID +" { % x y\n");
        sb.append("gsave translate "+postscriptID+".form execform grestore\n");
        sb.append("} def\n");
        sb.append("%%EndResource\n");
```

Comment: For SVG (which is a vector format), you should probably be able to convert to PS (as low-level operations). Many tools do this already. PS also supports embedded JPEG data (DCTDecode filter) which should save you from having to decode the JPEG first.

Comment: @haraldK thank you for your answer. Yes I found a tool named 'vectormagic' that will convert jpg or png to eps vector description and I hope to use this tool to resolve this issue. However it doesn't provide the functionality to resize the image but I should be able the find another tool or write some code to achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for useful feedback. I have removed that section from the body of the question and posted it separately as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot embed an SVG or PNG image in a PostScript program, becasue PostScript does not include any support for those formats. You would need to decode those to simple raster bitmaps first.

The logo you quote doesn't use an image. It draws the logo by drawing a series of shapes, and filling them. Its a vector description not an image.

You **could** convert a raster image into a series of rectangular fills; take each image sample in turn, calculate its position (and size) on the output device, draw a rectangle that size at the given position, and fill it with the colour values of the sample. This will produce an absolutely gigantic output file which will render very slowly.

Much better is to include the image data as an image. To draw an image in PostScript you use the `image` operator, which has two forms. I would reccomend that you use the dictionary form of the operator. The image operator is defined on page 607 of the PostScript Language Reference Manual (3rd edition), and explained in detail in section 4.10, starting on page 288, of the same reference.

Basically you need to set up the image dictionary with a number of parameters, Width, Height, BitsPerComponent, a DataSource to read the image data from (often currentfile) and an ImageMatrix which defines the size and position of the final image in user space. Now for JPEG images, you can then simply insert the compressed data stream and specify the DataSource as using the DCTDecode filter. The other image formats will need to be decoded and the image data inserted as raw samples or, if size is a concern, compressed with one of the available PostScript filters (such as Flate) and an appropriate Decode filter supplied with the DataSource.

As an example, here's the traditional turkey image, defined in level 2:

```
%!
50 10 translate  % Locate lower-left corner of square

/DrawTurkey {
0 setgray
<<
/ImageType 1
/Width 24
/Height 23
/ImageMatrix [.24 0 0 .23 0 0]
/BitsPerComponent 1
/Decode [1 0]
/MultipleDataSources false
/DataSource < 003B00 002700 002480 0E4940
114920 14B220 3CB650 75FE88
17FF8C 175F14 1C07E2 3803C4
703182 F8EDFC B2BBC2 BB6F84
31BFC2 18EA3C 0E3E00 07FC00
03F800 1E1800 1FF800 >
>> imagemask
} def

% Draw the turkey upright

24 2 div 23 2 div [.24 0 0 .23 0 0] transform 
exch (centre at x = ) print == ( y = ) print ==

0.5 setgray
0 0 100 100 rectfill
0 1 0 setrgbcolor
0 0 moveto 0 100 lineto stroke
0 0 1 setrgbcolor
0 0 moveto 100 0 lineto stroke
1 0 0 setrgbcolor
0 0 moveto 100 100 lineto stroke
DrawTurkey

showpage
```

Notice that this program embeds the image data in a hex string, you won't be able to do that if your image data exceeds 64Kb.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The alternative solution I have mentioned in the question is exactly trying to do what you are suggesting. I have updated the question with the code used to generate this file. It works well for grey colour images. However I am having trouble to create a colour image. I think there are problems with the data source (image data embedded as hex string) and parameters passed to the image dictionary. I guess I will have deep dive into the postscript reference manual to make it work especially to the section you have mentioned. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to resolve this issue by creating the vector description of the colour image using a JPG to EPS converter named "vectormagic". Then developed a function that will load this vector description using 'translate' (to specify location of the logo) and 'scale' (to resize the logo) commands. Also needed to surround it with 'gsave' and 'grestore' to avoid alignment issues of other elements in the report:

```
/UniversityLogoResource {
newpath
0 84.2 moveto
474.8 84.2 lineto
474.8 0 lineto
0 0 lineto
0 84.2 lineto
closepath
1 1 1 setrgbcolor 
fill
newpath
8.688 74.76 moveto
18.592 74.69 28.498 74.75 38.402 74.73 curveto
52.57 74.726 66.738 74.738 80.906 74.724 curveto
......
......
%full vector description retrieved via 'vectormagic' converter 
....
398.59 122.99 402.63 123.16 405.76 123.96 curveto
closepath
1.000 0.996 1.000 setrgbcolor
fill
} def

/DrawUniversityLogo {  
/translateX exch def
/translateY exch def
/scaleX exch def
/scaleY exch def


gsave

translateX translateY translate
scaleX scaleY scale
UniversityLogoResource

grestore

} def
```

Thank you everyone who supported to figure this out.